# How to make transparent magnifier?

Tags: css, canvas, svg, svg-filters

Some time ago i've seen websites where using cool transparency effect on mouseover.

How to make transparent element so when you hover on website background you can see an image underneath that area ?

Cant find any information on this, please help :)

Comment: your question is not very clear
try to add an example
or what you did so far and what needs fixing

Comment: Just change the opacity of the element when you hover ?

Comment: basically i want to see bg-one only in the circle like here : https://jsfiddle.net/9dqh88ff/ . I think it could be done with svg filters but i am not sure :)

Comment: It can be done with SVG filters but not easily. SVG 1.1 was supposed to have the capability to grab the background as a filter input but this was never supported by many browsers, and has been dropped from the new filters spec and marked "won't implement" by most browsers. There are workarounds, but they're not straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

OK some strategy and some example.

The strategy:

- place a background
- place some blocking over it
- make a `div` with the same background
- if the mouse moves, move this div
- if the `div` moves, move the background to the negative position of the main background..

Example:

```js
$(function(){
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY;

        var $t=$(".transfier");
        var newLeft =x-$t.width() / 2;
        var newTop= y-$t.height() / 2;
        $t.offset({
            top: newTop,
            left: newLeft
        });

        $t.css('background-position-x', 0 - x + $t.width() / 2);
        $t.css('background-position-y', 0 - y + $t.height() / 2);
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background: url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/height_canyon_retina_81205_3840x2400.jpg);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0px;
}

.transfier {
    background: url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/height_canyon_retina_81205_3840x2400.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid green;
}

.blockMyView {
    background-color: white;
    width: 75%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transfier"> hoi </div>
<div class="blockMyView"></div>
```